# How can seamless audio loops longer than 5 seconds be achieved in NativeScript?

Tags: nativescript

The `nativescript-audio` library results in a gap at the audio loop point and `nativescript-sound` only plays about the first five seconds of the track, so is only useful for sound effects and the likes. I'm trying to loop a few pieces of music several minutes in length.

Comment: Are you saying you are facing a buffer time (gap) while `loop` is on? The audio tracks are present in your local device?

Comment: @Manoj Yes to both questions.